# Registration Wall Causing Issue with AMP Validation

Tags: amp-html, amp-access

A company I am working with just launched an update to their AMP pages which included a registration wall to access articles. AMP pages were validating before the update but are now showing errors. The only change with the latest update is that the registration wall was added. From what I can see the registration wall was implemented using the recommended AMP-Access code

An example of one of these new AMP pages with the registration wall is available here: https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/atlanta-data-center-market-posts-very-impressive-numbers/?amp=1

This page validates when I use the Chrome AMP plugin so the code is good.
https://www.screencast.com/t/DhcTmSkky

But I am seeing errors across the board in Google Search Console.

When I use this tool https://search.google.com/test/amp validation fails.

We changed the access permissions on the non-amp version of another article as a test, which allowed the amp version to validate see: https://www.screencast.com/t/79sjjTw2pU

https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/how-to-build-an-inclusive-company-culture/ and https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/how-to-build-an-inclusive-company-culture/?amp=1

Can someone help me troubleshoot why access permission on non-amp pages are affecting validation of amp pages?

Updated the access permission for one non-amp page and this allowed the amp version of the page to validate. Amp and non-amp version of this test page are included below.

https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/how-to-build-an-inclusive-company-culture/ 
https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/how-to-build-an-inclusive-company-culture/?amp=1

Comment: So I ran the page through `search.google.com` and got the following error: "Referenced AMP URL is not an AMP". When I looked into this error is says: "A canonical page references an AMP that is not, in fact, an AMP page. Learn how a non-AMP page should reference an AMP page." My best guess is you need to add `?amp=1` to the canonical url and list the none amp page as `rel="alternate"` then do the opposite for he non-amp page.

Comment: So that error started showing up once we added the registration wall. Before that AMP pages validated. So AMP access is causing the issue. If you look at https://www.globest.com/2019/04/18/how-to-build-an-inclusive-company-culture/?amp=1 has the correct canonical tag https://www.screencast.com/t/S1J8useq and        the non amp version has the correct reference to the amp page https://www.screencast.com/t/ZcEB4yyofDSG.